# @window.event giving error in pyglet

Tags: python

I am using windows 10. I am trying to play mp4 or avi file using pyglet. I wrote this code,

```
import pyglet

vidPath = 'cc.avi'
window= pyglet.window.Window(fullscreen = True)
player = pyglet.media.Player()
source = pyglet.media.StreamingSource()
MediaLoad = pyglet.media.load(vidPath)

player.queue(MediaLoad)
player.play()



def on_draw():
    if player.source and player.source.video_format:
        player.get_texture().bilt(50,50)


pyglet.app.run()
```

After execution, only sound is playing and not the video appear. A black window pops up and sound starts but video is not showing.

I have tried

> @window.event

before

> def on_draw:

but it gives lots of errors:

```
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
=================== RESTART: E:\HVPA\Files\pygletplayer.py ===================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\HVPA\Files\pygletplayer.py", line 21, in <module>
    pyglet.app.run()
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\__init__.py", line 138, in run
    event_loop.run()
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 142, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 154, in _run
    timeout = self.idle()
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 281, in idle
    window.dispatch_event('on_draw')
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\__init__.py", line 1232, in dispatch_event
    if EventDispatcher.dispatch_event(self, *args) != False:
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyglet\event.py", line 357, in dispatch_event
    if handler(*args):
  File "E:\HVPA\Files\pygletplayer.py", line 16, in on_draw
    player.get_texture().bilt(50,50)
AttributeError: 'TextureRegion' object has no attribute 'bilt'
>>>
```

I also tried decorators without @ but same errors appeared, but without @window.event no error occurs but sound plays and video doesn't show.

Comment: Please copy-paste errors directly into your question (using [code formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/353194)), don't include screenshots of them.

Comment: ok I did it. Please help me for my issue.

Comment: Why you don't read the error log. It says clearly: AttributeError: 'TextureRegion' object has no attribute 'bilt'
Repleace the word bilt with blit.

Comment: Thank you....it worked....errors are gone....but still only audio is playing , not video